# PHP String and foreach multiple results

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

I have searched around for this but not had any luck.
I have a foreach loop which gets the row id from  one table.

```
$str = '';

    foreach ($ctrl->db->get_where('db.table',['id'=>$row['id']],2)->result_array() as $value){
$str .= $value['completed'];
}
$row['completed'] = $str;
```

This foreach when printed brings multiple array results

```
Array
(
    [id] => 9053
    [job_id] => 19147
    [type] => value
    [when] => 2018-11-16 10:54:58
    [notes] => 
    [finished] => Y
    [completed] => 2018-11-16 10:54:58

)
Array
(
    [id] => 8053
    [job_id] => 19147
    [type] => value
    [when] => 2018-05-16 10:54:58
    [notes] => 
    [finished] => Y
    [completed] => 2018-05-16 10:54:58

)
```

These results are being pushed onto a row for a table view based on the Job_id column.
How can I specify which job_id result to select if I want the completed value from each of them since the $row['completed'] just returns one of them.

Comment: Your question is unclear. But one hint: your overwrite the content of `$str` in each and every iteration of your `foreach` loop. That is why the final `$row['completed']` contains only a single entry.

Comment: Had a typo within foreach.  Don't think it changes anything.
Ok so if  I'm overwriting it within the loop should i have it outside the loop?

Comment: You should use `$str .= $value['completed'];` - and then after the loop you `$str` will have all the "completed" value. BTW, I think array will be better for you to use here